# WCF service with transport level security - Service unavailable

Tags: c#, wcf

I have service with transport level security when I have changed http to https , i am unable to expose operation contract as it is showing site can't be reached in browser itself.

Below is my config file

```
<wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="transport">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None">

            </transport>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>



 <service name="WcfService1.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding"  bindingConfiguration="transport" contract="WcfService1.IService1"></endpoint>
      </service>
```

My service is hosted via IISExpress where Project URL is as below
https://localhost:49500/

And also SSL is enabled with SSL URL which is different from http URL.

I have tried many possible way as stated in SO but couldn't able to find solution for this.
Please help!

Comment: If you turn off all security, can you reach the service in a browser then?

Comment: Yes if i turn off i am able to reach the service.

Comment: See if [this article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx) doesn't help you. IIS may be missing a binding for that port in combination with SSL.

Comment: i am using iisexpress where project url and SSL url both are pointing to same port , anything else i am missing here?